# Can this be done in a MySQL query, or does it need to be done in PHP? (serverside)

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table:

```
id
first
last
institution
address
space1_1_value
space1_2_value
space2_1_value
space2_2_value
space3_1_value
space3_2_value
agreement
```

(This is trimmed down field count for example sake).

I initially needed to break down each 'space x' grouping (ie: space1.x, space2.x, space3.x) to its own ROWS  (even though all data was in 1 record/row)

> id | first | last | institution | address | space1_1_value |
>   space1_2_value | agreement

If there are value in space2_1_value then:

> id | first | last | institution | address | space2_1_value |
>   space2_2_value | agreement

If there are value in space3_1_value then:

> id | first | last | institution | address |  space3_1_value |
>   space3_2_value | agreement

This was worked out by using the following query:

```
SELECT first, last, space1_1_value as space_value FROM report
UNION ALL
SELECT first, last, space2_2_value as space_value FROM report WHERE space2_2_value <> ''
UNION ALL
SELECT first, last, space3_3_value as space_value FROM report WHERE space3_3_value <> ''
ORDER BY first
```

However I have been tasked to break this down even further, but I am not sure if this is even possible with a query, or if in fact would need to be done on the backend/PHP side of things?

So keeping the above directive in mind (which is a requirement):

So for each SPACE1.x group,  there is a column with a comma delimited values in it.

For this, we'll say all space1_2_value, space2_2_value & space3_3_value cols hold something like:

```
March 3,March 5,March 6
March 1,March 2
Feb 27
```

for example.

So each col could have 1 to many comma delimited values.

Is there a way in MySQL to break up these values, and return a mirroring row for each one?  Or something that simple needs to be done on the backend (PHP) side of thing?

I gave a few minutes to try and think how'd I'd do it in PHP.

But am getting caught up foreach() loops without any index?  (or just a plain for() loop WITH index, but not a lot of overhead to check if each $value is blank (manually).

Comment: So, each space_x_x_value has a N number of values (separated by comma) and you need to turn each one of those into his own rows (wich will repeat (id, first, last, institution, agreement)?

Comment: The column names in you query don't match the names in the table description.

Comment: Correct. (At least I think you got it!)  LOL..  

* The UNION ALL stuff needs to be there.. and is my first step.

The UNION ALL stuff already breaks my 'rows' into more rows based on content being in the Space 1, 2 or 3 sections..  (based on a space 1, 2 or 3 request)

(query above works as it should).

I'm trying to now extend that to parse the .

* in EACH ROW there are potentially '3' cols that can have comma delimited values in it as well..

So in these cols:

 space1_2_value, space2_2_value & space3_3_value... if there are values, I need to do as you describe.

Comment: @Paul Spiegel 

Just a typo while tryign to get something for everyone to view..

As mentioned.. the UNION ALL stuff is already working as is.  I'm focused on how to break down the cols delimited data to do as LordNeo describes.

Comment: Use PHP and [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php). It's no fun to split a string in SQL.

Comment: Thats what I am attempting.. but I cant seem to wrap my brain around:

foreach() loop with an index? (how do I dup these 'rows; with a new value form the exploded array?)

for() loop WITH index is nice.. but I'm sure how I can now validate if a field is empty?  (without having all cols name in a manual check)

Is there a generic way to check a value using a FOR() loop (not foreach)?

Im accessing like so currently:
$results[$i]['Dates_Requested']

Can you do:
$results[$i]

?? Doesnt seem so? Seems like I need a valid col name in there

Comment: @whispers next time someone makes an unnecessary comment, just flag it, no need to respond. Thanks. (flag this when you see it.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done in *sql*. One way would be to use a "helper table" with just integers that you can `join` your data against to get your row several times and then to extract just the `n`-th subelement.

Try this:

```sql
-- helper table with a listof integers from 1 to 10
create table _int_1_10 (id int primary key);
insert into _int_1_10 (id) 
values (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9), (10);

-- some example data 
create table test_strexplode (
   id int primary key, 
   space_value_1 varchar(200),
   space_value_2 varchar(200)
);

insert into test_strexplode (id, space_value_1, space_value_2)
values (1, 'row 1', 'March 3,March 5,March 6 March 1,March 2 Feb 27'),
       (2, 'row 2', 'March 3,,March 5'),
       (3, 'row 3', '');

select space_value_1, 
  _int_1_10.id,
  -- extracts the "_int_1_10.id"th element
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(
       space_value_2,',',_int_1_10.id),',',-1) as subentry
from test_strexplode
join _int_1_10 
on _int_1_10.id <= 
   -- number of elements in your string (= number of "," + 1)
   char_length(space_value_2) - char_length(replace(space_value_2, ',', '')) + 1
order by test_strexplode.id, _int_1_10.id;
```

This will give you:

```sql
+---------------+----+-----------------+
| space_value_1 | id | subentry        |
+---------------+----+-----------------+
| row 1         | 1  | March 3         | 
| row 1         | 2  | March 5         |
| row 1         | 3  | March 6 March 1 |
| row 1         | 4  | March 2 Feb 27  |
| row 2         | 1  | March 3         |
| row 2         | 2  |                 |
| row 2         | 3  | March 5         |
| row 3         | 1  |                 |
+---------------+----+-----------------+
```

I used your sample data that is missing some `,`, which is why the result contains e.g. `March 2 Feb 27`. Also note that some subentries are empty (as my sample data includes empty entries); you may or may not want to filter them out. Your integer table will obviously have to contain numbers at least up to the maximum number of elements you expect to have in any of your rows (and if it contains a `0` or negative numbers, filter them out in the `on`-clause).

[`substring_index(str,delim,count)`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) returns the substring from string `str` before `count` occurrences of the delimiter `delim`. The full statement for `subentry` will, for a positive number, return either the `_int_1_10.id`-th element or, if the string has less elements, the last element.

The `on`-clause thus calculates the number of elements (by counting the number of `,`) to prevent getting the last element several times. If your string does not contain any empty elements (like the `,,` in my sample data), you don't need that part but could add an empty element to mark the end of the list.

You can apply this code to your whole resultset e.g. by using

```sql
...
from (select ... 
         space1_1_value as space_value_1,
         space1_2_value as space_value_2
      ...
      union all ... union all ... ) as test_strexplode 
join _int_1_10 ...
```

It will work, but it might be slow. It cannot use an index on the `space*_2_value`-columns and will have to do a lot of joining and string-evaluation. You cannot do much about it though, except normalizing your data.

If it is useful to do this in *sql* will probably depend on what you are doing with the data. If you are just going to display it in an html-table on a webpage, it might be both easier and faster to just loop through the array in *php*. To sort, filter or `join` your resultset, it's probably much easier to implement (and likely faster) in *sql*, maybe even if you are using it in a framework. If you are going to update the values, it will be much easier to do in *php*, as it is most likely going to be a mess in *sql* (on this resultset).

Comment: Thanks!  I'll pick it apart when I get to work tomorrow..  (just as another way to approach things if I ever find myself here again!)

What I ended up doing was hacking it up on the PHP side of things.. (took a bit of tinkering..but in the end pretty straight forward once I wrapped my brain around a decent approach) 

Updated original post with PHP solution.

Comment: @whispers: are you able to accept this answer? It is not mandatory, but it is nice if a lot of volunteer effort has been expended, as seems to be the case here.

Comment: I hadnt gotten around to actually test it...  (hence why I hadnt circled back)..

that being said..  why are you going through several of my posts?  (you have made comments or edits on several separate posts of mine now?.. as in today.)

Comment: @whispers: I did not see your comment until just now - please use `@halfer` to ping me if you'd like to ask something. It is quite normal to edit posts on Stack Exchange sites, see [Why can people edit my posts?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing). Thanks for accepting this answer!

Answer (score 0):

*Posted answer on behalf of the OP*.

I rolled my own PHP solution for this (but thanks @Solarflare for a SQL solution).

PHP: (obviously using the UNION ALL QUERY...etc)

```
$getRequests_stmt = $conn->prepare($getRequests_sql);
$getRequests_stmt->execute();
$getRequests_stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$results = $getRequests_stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$colcount = $getRequests_stmt->columnCount();
$rowcount = $getRequests_stmt->rowCount();
$date = new DateTime();
$currdate = "Results as of: ".$date->format('m-d-Y H:i:s');
$namedate = $date->format('m-d-Y-H_i_s');    
//Get Headers
for ($i = 0; $i < $colcount; $i++) {
                $col = $getRequests_stmt->getColumnMeta($i);
    $colname = $col['name'];
    $header .= $colname . "\t";
}

//Get Row Data
while ($results = $getRequests_stmt->fetch()){                                
                $line = '';
    foreach($results as $key => $value) {
        if ((!isset($value)) || ($value == '')) {
            $value = "\t";
        } else {
            $value = str_replace('"', '""', $value);
            $value = '"' . $value . '"' . "\t";
        }
        $line .= $value;
    }
    $data .= trim($line) . "\n";        
}

//Data check
$data = str_replace("\r", '', $data);
if ($data == '') { 
    $data = "\n(0) space requests found\n";
}

//Export spreadsheet...
```