# How can I display all elements from JSON Document in Mysql

Tags: mysql, json

I have inserted below data to column doc.

```
insert into tbl_temp (sid, doc) 
 values('M000001',
        '{"doclist":
     [{"PID":"F000001","name":"Roi","Age":"32","City":"OLI","Occ":"Reader"},
      {"PID":"F000002","name":"Joi","Age":"33","City":"LND","Occ":"Runner"},
      {"PID":"F000003","name":"Kloi","Age":"34","City":"NYC","Occ":"Writer"} 
        ]
        }'
      )
```

Now I wanted to display all the PIDs, so I did query like below in mysql.

```
SELECT 
    SID, 
    json_extract(doc, '$.doclist[*].PID') AS PID
FROM MAT.TBL_temp;
```

But I am getting result like this -

```
SID        Shortlisted
```

M000001        ["F000001", "F000002", "F000003"]

But I want result like below

```
SID        Shortlisted
M000001    "F000001"
M000001    "F000002"
M000001    "F000003"
```

Also not sure why I am getting '[]' in output.

When I run the below query (for single element), it worked fine

```
SELECT 
    SID, 
    json_extract(doc, '$.doclist[0].PID') AS PID
FROM MAT.TBL_temp;
```

Result:

```
  SID        Shortlisted
  M000001    "F000001"
```

Comment: While MySQL can perform some operations on it, json (unstructured data) doesn't work very well in a relational database (the "s" in sql stands for "structured"), so there is no native function to do this. I wrote [an explode query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45303592/6248528) (split an array into rows) for a slightly different situation that you can use here too (after removing the `[`,`]`). But generally, if you want to process (e.g. update, join, index) data in mysql efficiently, you have to store it in a normalized way (at least currently, more json functions might be added in the future).

Comment: Regarding your doubt: "why I am getting '[]' in output", see [`JSON_EXTRACT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-extract) documentation: `The return value consists of all values matched by the path arguments. If it is possible that those arguments could return multiple values, the matched values are autowrapped as an array, in the order corresponding to the paths that produced them. Otherwise, the return value is the single matched value.`.